# prevent form from submitting and make another button submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div inside a form, once the user clicks a button, i slideup the div and slideDown a new div, and from the new div the user can  submit, but i need the submit button to be on the first div so the javascript can work because i put required on the fields, how can i make the first button a submit button then prevent it from submitting and instead slideUp the old div and slideDown the new div and in the new div's button is the actual summation?

right now i have the firt div's button as type="button" and the new div's button as the submit one, but like that it doesn't validate if one of thee input fields is empty, i know i should use preventDefault() but javascript syntax drives me crazy i don't know how to write it,please help me.

```
<form>
  <div id="choosing">
    //inputs

    <button type="button" id="show"> Finish up</button>
  </div>
  
  <div id="confirmation">
     
    <button type="submit" id="formSubmit"> Finish up</button
  </div>
```

the javascript

```
$('#show').click(function(e) {
     
  $("#choosing").slideUp();
  $("#confirmation").slideDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure if I got your question right. However, this might help you.

We can disable the confirmation button, so it's not clickable at the beginning.

```
<form>
    <div id="choosing">
      //input
      <button type="button" id="show"> Finish up</button>
    </div>
    <div id="confirmation">  
      <button type="submit" id="formSubmit" disabled> Finish up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then in JS we define a function that will be executed if the show button was clicked. In that function the confirmation button will be enabled and do is clickable again

```
$(document).on('click', '#show', function() {
    $("#choosing").slideUp();
    //enable confirmation button
    const formSubmit = document.getElementById('formSubmit');
    formSubmit.disabled = false;
    $("#confirmation").slideDown();
});
```

Hope that helps, let me know if it worked as wished.